# any() with sequence of strings

Tags: python, any

Why does

```
any(['','foo'])
```

raise the exception

```
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

I thought it should evaluate to `True`, because

- `bool('')` evaluates to `False`
- `bool('foo')` evaluates to `True`
- I though `any()` could be used with any sequence of objects that are convertible to `bool`

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: [Sure you did not overwrite `any()` with your own function?](http://ideone.com/DmPFF)

Comment: Works for me. Does sound like you overwrote `any()`.

Comment: Python 2.7.3, `any(['', 'foo'])` returns `True`

Comment: you can be lucky that you had no generator as `any(False for x in range(1))` returns also `True` for numpy's `any`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are accidentally calling [`numpy.any()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) instead of the built-in [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any). The latter does work for your example.

To fix this, you need to sort out the imports. Look for `from numpy import *` and `from numpy import any`, and for similar imports involving `scipy` and `pylab`.

Comment: I did no explicit imports. But I ran the code in an IPython console that I had started with the --pylab option.